# How to kill nodes in ROS2?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, ros-crystal, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS we have `rosnode kill -a`. Do we have something like this in ROS2?

I tried `ros2 node kill`, but it didn't work.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS | ROS2 Crystal | Gazebo 9.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323329/how-to-kill-nodes-in-ros2?/) by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-05-16

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik there is no `rosnode kill` in ROS 2.

ROS 2 introduces the concept of *managed nodes*, which have a node lifecycle ([ROS2 Design: Managed nodes](https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html)).

With nodes that support it you can then use

```
ros2 lifecycle set <nodename> shutdown
```

which should make the node with name `nodename` transition to its *shutdown* state and consequently shutdown the process.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-05-17**:
Can confirm, there is no feature to kill nodes remotely. This feature was related to enforcing node name uniqueness (duplicate names would cause one of the nodes to be killed), but we haven't addressed that yet.

**Comment by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) on 2021-02-03**:
@gvdhoorn It does not work in my system. I do `ros2 node list` which gives me `/pp/cam0`. Then I do `ros2 lifecycle set /pp/cam0 shutdown` and the response is `Node not found`. Any idea how to fix this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-04**:
I have no idea.

I would suggest to first make sure `/pp/cam0` is actually a lifecycle node. If it isn't, then `ros2 lifecycle` is not going to be of any help.

**Comment by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) on 2021-02-04**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks! Does that mean that there is no command in ROS2 foxy to shut down a node if the node does not have its lifecycle implemented? Nothing has really changed since May 2019 when you answered this question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-04**:\

> Nothing has really changed since May 2019 when you answered this question?

well, 'nothing' is a bit strong, but I don't believe there is a "kill node" command in ROS 2 in general, and I doubt it will ever be added.

See the rationale added by @William.

Killing nodes is process management, which is something the OS does best. ROS should not duplicate that (unloading components is something else).

Answer (score 0):

To handle the specific use-case of needing to kill all nodes (i.e., the entire launch) when one or more nodes exit/fail, you can [follow the procedure here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ros2-launch-required-nodes) of setting a node as `required` when launching from xml or setting an `on_exit` behavior in a python launch file. In the below example, if this node were to shut down or fail, all other nodes would be killed.

```
import launch
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package="demo_nodes_py",
            node_executable="talker",
            node_name="talker",
            output="screen"),

        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package="demo_nodes_py",
            node_executable="listener_qos",
            node_name="listener",
            output="screen",
            arguments=["--number_of_cycles", "1"],
            on_exit=launch.actions.Shutdown())  # here
    ])
```